# How to create angled ribbon with textview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to create such a list of items in android, I am able to complete almost everything except the orange ribbon on the right top corner, I tried different methods to achieve this UI element but none of them works properly for me. I tried rotating a text view by 45º with the ribbon image as background but the edges of the ribbon weren't perfect I also tried adding the ribbon as an image view and placed a text view on top of that but It was really difficult to place the ribbon and text view like this. So what is the easiest and most efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: 1]

Comment: What is your layout? ConstraintLayout? Also, rotating a _TextView_ seems like the way to go. What was wrong with the edges when you did this?

Comment: @Cheticamp The edges were not filling like the UI, but its fine I found solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a native android component that supports such a feature. You can create a custom view making use of the path. Here is a great [tutorial](https://developpaper.com/android-realizes-the-effect-of-slanting-label-surround-effect-in-the-upper-left-corner-other-corners/) if you want to follow it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Put this `TextView` into your `FrameLayout`/`CardView`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff8f00"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="25% Off"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:paddingStart="30dp"
    android:paddingEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-20dp"
    android:rotation="45"
    />
```

To achieve best look, play with `padding` and `margin` attributes.

Comment: Are you sure this will generate the expected output?

Comment: Sure. I already use it in my projects.